# How to represent Algebraic Variables?

Tags: python-3.x

For example, how do I have python do something like:

```
10/x=number>0
```

I know that the code above is completely wrong but I just want to know if there is a way to represent an unknown number.

Comment: Sounds like you might be after the [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) library

Comment: How do I represent x though with this library.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation/try a tutorial - see if it's what you're after...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`SymPy`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/tutorial.html) is what you are looking for. Search that page for "symbolic variables". But if I understood you right, this is a solution for your case: `number = lambda x: 10 / x > 0`